# Guardar en lista

Tags: c#

En este bloque estoy haciendo un `insert` de diferentes datos que se esta recorriendo con un `foreach`, después los agrega, con esto
no tengo ningún problema, lo que necesito es que de alguna manera, almacenar ya sea en una lista solamente el `SERIAL`, ya que haré uso
mas adelante de estos para otro `insert`.

```
string sql = "insert ..."
conexion.Open();
using (var comando = new OracleCommand(sql, conexion)){
 foreach (Information item in this){
    if (item.XXXXX != null){
          comando.Parameters.Clear();
          comando.Parameters.Add(":XXXXX", item.XXXXX);
          comando.Parameters.Add(":SERIAL",item.SERIAL);
          comando.Parameters.Add(":XXXXX", item.XXXXX);
          comando.Parameters.Add(":XXXXX", item.XXXXX);
          comando.Parameters.Add(":XXXXX", item.XXXXX);
          comando.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: puedes agregarlos a un array en cada iteracion del foreach mediante una varible, cuando vayas a utilzar nuevamente el SERIAL recorre el array de Seriales y los vas utilizando nuevamente.

Comment: Coloca un título  de pregunta más especifico. No se infiere mucho de el.

Answer (score 1):

Si tienes una lista con varias propiedades no necesitas pasar a otra cuendo iteras en el insert, podrias obtenerlo cuando quieras aplicando un linq

```
List<string> serials = this.Where(x=>x.XXXXX != null).Select(x=>x.SERIAL).ToList();
```

asi de facil obtienes la lista independiente de la iteracion del insert, ya que puedes filtrarla y obtener los datos del serial

Comment: Que es la  "x" seguido de =>?

Comment: es una expresion lambda https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/statements-expressions-operators/lambda-expressions

Answer (score 0):

Imaginaando que estas usando ASPX, entonces intenta con lo siguiente:

```
List<string> listaSeriales = new List<string>();
string sql = "insert ..."
conexion.Open();
using (var comando = new OracleCommand(sql, conexion)){
    foreach (Information item in this){
        if (item.XXXXX != null){
            comando.Parameters.Clear();
            comando.Parameters.Add(":XXXXX", item.XXXXX);
            comando.Parameters.Add(":SERIAL",item.SERIAL);
            listaSeriales.Add(item.SERIAL);
            comando.Parameters.Add(":XXXXX", item.XXXXX);
            comando.Parameters.Add(":XXXXX", item.XXXXX);
            comando.Parameters.Add(":XXXXX", item.XXXXX);
            comando.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
    }
    ViewState["ListaSeriales"] = listaSeriales;
}
```

Luego en la parte que ocupas usar la lista con los seriales, entonces obtiene lo que guardaste en el viewstate;

```
List<string> listaSeriales = new List<string>();
listaSeriales = (List<string>)ViewState["ListaSeriales"];
```